# Saving struct to m5stacks preference

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to save an array of a struc to my m5stack, but it is restarting all the time, so there is a code error...
Loading is working, but on saving it crashes. Not the complete array is filled, only 2 presets are filled.

```
#include <Preferences.h> // Store settings in EEPROM

struct preset_time_t
{
    uint8_t active = 0;
    uint8_t min = 0;
    uint8_t hour = 0;
    int32_t duration = 0;
};

// Number of presets
preset_time_t preset[10];
Preferences pref;


// Load schedule from eeprom
void loadSchedule()
{
  pref.begin("Presets, true");
   
  size_t schLen = pref.getBytesLength("presets");
  char buffer[schLen]; // prepare a buffer for the data
  pref.getBytes("presets", buffer, schLen);
  if (schLen % sizeof(preset_time_t)) { // simple check that data fits
    // Data not correct size
    return;
  }
  memcpy(preset, buffer, schLen);
  pref.end();
}

// Save schedule to eeprom
void saveSchedule()
{
  pref.begin("Presets");
  pref.putBytes("presets", preset, sizeof(preset));
  pref.end();
}
```

Comment: Your problem might be hidden in `<Preferences.h>` ? What's the value of `schlen`? 
`sizeof(preset_time_t)` might depend on your arduino type and compiler, as not everywhere a int32_t will start on an odd address.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem(s)

timer0 has to be disabled during writing Preferences, otherwise ESP32 crashes...

```
pref.begin("Presets, true");
```

Has to be

```
pref.begin("Presets", true);
```